# Why is not update textblock while update it`s source

Tags: wpf, data-binding

[Please Checkout this Pictute](http://www.procesta.com/Images/TextblockDataBinding.png)

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Person()
    {
    }
    public string newPerson(string Value)
    {
        this.Name = Value;
        return "";
    }
    public Person(string value)
    {

        this.name = value;

    }
    public string Name
    {

        get { return name; }

        set
        {

            name = value;

            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated

            OnPropertyChanged("Name");

        }

    }
    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {

            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }

    }
```

.
XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Person x:Key="NewPerson" Name="shuvo"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AddNewPerson" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Person}" MethodName="newPerson">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>yahoo</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,57,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource NewPerson},Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,149,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource AddNewPerson}, Path=MethodParameters[0],BindsDirectlyToSource=True,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The *ObjectDataProvider* is creating a new instance of the *Person* class and then calling the *newPerson* method of that new instance. This new instance is not connected to the already existing *Person* instance that you declared in the window resources as *NewPerson*. Therefore the object data provider is calling a method that has no effect.

You should mofify the *ObjectDataProvider* to use the *ObjectInstance* property and bind it to the windows resources defined *NewPerson*. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) for more information.